# TFS and Dangling Commits that are referenced in backlog items

Tags: git, tfs

I have a TFS source code repository configured to use git. I follow the rule about not force pushing for any branch that another developer uses – however, our team has a rule that says we can ‘own’ branches on the remote so we can back our code up. Other developers are not to branch from these ‘owned’ branches. Often during my day to day work I’ll reorder local commits, merge local commits, rework the comments, etc. Then at some point I want to push my changes, so they are not only on my laptop. Of course, if I do many of those previously listed operations the remote will not allow the push. So I force push. At some point I’m happy with my work and I’ll create a pull request from this ‘owned’ branch to our develop branch – at which point I also delete the local I’ve been using. Once the PR is approved and merged into develop the original remote ‘owend’ feature branch is also deleted.

All works fine.
However, TFS has a feature that allows you to link commits to work items. To use this feature you add #IdOfWorkItem to the commit. TFS will auto link the work item to the commit and you can browse that commit from the work item. It’s great.

However, it will also link these commits from our ‘owned’ feature branches. I wondered what would happen if I add a #Id comment, push, then destruct the commit and force push. As expected the commit is linked to the respective back log item with the given #id. What was not expected is that when I destruct that commit by a force push the link remains and can even be navigated to.
I have since learned that this is a dangling commit and is quite normal in git. There are various ways to deal with them, and they can get cleaned up.

**The questions:**

1. Does TFS git ever clean up dangling commits?
2. What happens to the link between the commit and the work item if the
   commit is purged
3. Is the above described behavior destructive to TFS – will the git
   repository break at some point do to these dangling commits?
4. If force pushing in this situation isn’t
   the answer what is the advice for backing up local repositories
   before you push them to the remote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Does TFS git ever clean up dangling commits?

> No.

2. What happens to the link between the commit and the work item if the
   commit is purged

> The link still exists, you have to remove it manually. Even though the
>   commit is destructed, it still exists but not belong to any branch any
>   more.

3. Is the above described behavior destructive to TFS – will the git
   repository break at some point do to these dangling commits?

> Basically, the answer is No.

4. If force pushing in this situation isn’t the answer what is the
   advice for backing up local repositories before you push them to the
   remote?

> Instead of force pushing, you could use just push to back up your
>   repo.